# multiprocessing io bound tasks in python

Tags: python

I am trying to understand the multiprocessing pool in python 3.5
here is what I made so far in terms of understanding

```
def f(file):
    with gzip.open(file, 'r') as fin:
        for line in fin:
            pass
    return line

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import time
    fl_list = ["six.txt.gz","six.txt1.gz"]
    start = time.time()
    with Pool(4) as p:
        p.map(f, fl_list)
    end = time.time()
    print("multiprocess",end - start)
    start = time.time()
    for fl in fl_list:
        f(fl)
    end = time.time()
    print("Serial Process:",end - start)
```

Results:

all files are identical

```
for 2 files:
multiprocess: 9.002790212631226
Serial Process: 14.341188907623291

for 4 files:
multiprocess: 16.881436586380005
Serial Process: 29.185585498809814

for 6 files:
multiprocess: 23.094680309295654
Serial Process: 45.07802891731262
```

Am I missing anything? I mean shouldn't multi processing time remain constant?

Comment: You have only one hard disk.  You can only input the files in a linear fashion, so that's a bottleneck.

Comment: I got it. Why multiprocess have edge then? 23 vs. 45? Can I Improve My code?

Comment: Disk i/o can't be shared across multiple cores, but any CPU-based number crunching will run in parallel.  It seems like you are reading in some zip archives, so the decompression calculations will speed up.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for explaining.